# Program trapped in long loop - how to exit?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that finds two prime factors of a number. (for my rsa decrypting homework)

I've just started to Python so ı am a beginner and ı didn't understand why this program doesn't work after finding factors.

`p` and `q` are the factor numbers, ı wrote it manually after program calculated.

I want to print `totientfonk` but I can't. Program doesn't close by the way. It is just waiting.

```
nsayisi = 27765438273271

for i in range(2,nsayisi):
    if nsayisi % i == 0:
     print(i)


p = 4812569
q = 5769359

totientfonk = (p-1) * (q-1)

print(totientfonk)
```

Comment: That's a big `for` loop. It will take a while to go through all of those iterations. Quite a long while, I can't test speed atm to get some idea.

Comment: So do you recommend to wait, or is there any other way to speed up  the process?

Comment: I'd recommend two things; 1) test the general approach with smaller numbers to get your desired output (`print` is pretty useless in any real system, so you'll probably want to do something with the output) and 2; test run time with a `for` loop that is orders of magnitude smaller to get a sense of how long your final code will take to run.

Comment: Actually yes, ı don't need to print(i) line. It will be enough to calculate these factors but ı can't assing another variable with for loop? How can ı assign these two factors to two different variable like p and q?

Comment: You should exit from the loop once you've found both factors. It doesn't take very long for your loop to get up to 5,769,359, but it will take quite a while to get all the way to `27,765,438,273,271`.

Comment: How can ı exit from loop? I've tried to use break and continue commands.(because ı just know these two :) ) When ı use break command program closed after first factor. It didn't calculated the second one and jumped  print totientfonk.

Comment: tohajiile: To exit the loop, at the top of it just add an `if i > stop_value: break`. Where `stop_value` is either a hardcoded constant or the name of a variable with the integer value in it.

Comment: martineau: I added the if i > stop_value: break but couldn't define stop_value. It has to be second i value but how can ı define before find the i values with loop? sorry for the question, probably it is too easy but ı can't understand.

Comment: When do you want the loop to exit? When it finds two factors for `nsayisi`? As soon as your `print(i)` statement is executed, break there.

Comment: Harvey: Yes ı want to break after it finds two factors. I added the break command after print(i) statement but it finds first factor when ı do that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
nsayisi = 27765438273271
for p in range(2, nsayisi):
    if nsayisi % p == 0:
        q = nsayisi // p
        break
print(p, q)
totientfonk = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
print(totientfonk)
```

Comment: Yess, exactly that was what ı want. Thank you. it was unnecessary to define an integer i  value ı see. But what does this line do?  q = nsayisi // p

Comment: tohajiile: That line computes the other factor—since `p` goes evenly into `nsayisi` (zero remainder) it's one of them, and the integer quotient `q` calculated is the other. That said, although this seems relatively fast, it isn't finding the **prime** factors of `nsayisi`, just two whole number factors (assuming `nsayisi` isn't prime itself). For example with `nsayisi = 8`, the result will be `2`, `4` and the second number isn't a prime.